# JQuery Datatables row index not showing according page

Tags: jquery, indexing, row, datatables

I am using the [Jquery datatables](http://datatables.net/) to build a table. I need a row index for every row that I have. But the row index reset to 1 when I switch to the next page. 
I need the row index continues from the first page last row, mean if my page size is 10, then the 2nd page first row should start with 11 and not 1.
My problem is same with this image [SAMPLE](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/18686477/Untitled.png).
Please help me check what wrong with my code. Thanks alot :)

```
var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": sAjaxPage.toString(),
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                    debugger;
                    var index = iDisplayIndexFull + 1;
                    $("td:first", nRow).html(index);
                    return nRow;
                },
      "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
                    aoData.push({ "name": "pTransactionDateFrom", "value": pTransactionDateFrom });
                    aoData.push({ "name": "pTransactionDateTo", "value": pTransactionDateTo });
                    aoData.push({ "name": "pTransactionNo", "value": pTransactionNo });
                },
                "aoColumns": [
                        {
                            "bSort": false,
                            "bSearchable": false,
                            "bSortable": false,
                            "bFilter": false
                        },
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null
                    ]
});
```

Comment: Seems to be working. I used the same `fnRowCallback` that you have used. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qfqQN/)

Comment: Thanks for helping, but, it still not function at my page. :( I am using Jquery datatable version 1.9.4 too.

Comment: is there any way to get the oTables.iDisplayStart value at the javascript, i plan to get the row index by **iDisplayStart +iDisplayIndexFull + 1;**. I search on google but cant get it. :(

Comment: I found the way to get the IDisplayStart at [link](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnGetHiddenNodes). Using api 
fnPagingInfo.
My current  fnRowCallback is `  "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                    debugger;

                    var numStart =  this.fnPagingInfo().iStart;

                    var index = numStart +  iDisplayIndexFull + 1;
                    $("td:first", nRow).html(index);
                    return nRow;
                },`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a way to solve my problem. Not the standard but it's working. :)

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {

                    var numStart =  this.fnPagingInfo().iStart;

                    var index = numStart +  iDisplayIndexFull + 1;
                    $("td:first", nRow).html(index);
                    return nRow;
                },
```

The datatable api is http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnPagingInfo

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function (oSettings) {
    return {
        "iStart": oSettings._iDisplayStart,
        "iEnd": oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
        "iLength": oSettings._iDisplayLength,
        "iTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
        "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
        "iPage": Math.ceil(oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength),
        "iTotalPages": Math.ceil(oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength)
    };
};
```